# How to take only the second value from the div and write it to a variable

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Please tell me how to extract from the entire code and write to the variable only the text 'NEEEED'

```
<div id="statsBlock">
  <h1>JustText</h1>
     <div class="firmStatsDescr">
     <div class="firmInfo">HelloText<strong>OtherText</strong></div>
     <div class="firmInfo">JustText <strong>NEEEED</strong></div>
     <div class="firmInfo">hello</div>
  <h2>otherText.</h2>


Code:
soup.find_all("div", {"class": "firmInfo"})
```

But what to do next? How to extract only the second (the NEEEED text) and write it to a variable?

Comment: how about using `[1]` to get second item - and laster `find("strong")`

Answer (score 1):

It's the direct child `strong` element of a  parent element with class `firmInfo`. That parent is the only even numbered child element sharing that class so you can use `:nth-child(even)`. Anchor the selector list with a leftmost id selector for ancestor.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html='''
<div id="statsBlock">
  <h1>JustText</h1>
     <div class="firmStatsDescr">Hey</div>
     <div class="firmInfo">HelloText<strong>OtherText</strong></div>
     <div class="firmInfo">JustText <strong>NEEEED</strong></div>
     <div class="firmInfo">hello</div>
  <h2>otherText.</h2>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml') # or 'html.parser'

print(soup.select_one('#statsBlock .firmInfo:nth-child(even) > strong').text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to extract it in different ways, but in the end it turned out that I was trying to extract everything from another site) (Forgot to change the link)

Comment: How does that alter the question as posed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
html='''
<div id="statsBlock">
  <h1>JustText</h1>
     <div class="firmStatsDescr">Hey</div>
     <div class="firmInfo">HelloText<strong>OtherText</strong></div>
     <div class="firmInfo">JustText <strong>NEEEED</strong></div>
     <div class="firmInfo">hello</div>
  <h2>otherText.</h2>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup= BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

txt=soup.select_one('#statsBlock h1 + div + div + div strong').text
print(txt)
```

Output:

```
NEEEED
```